# Need help modifying a javascript from a website

Tags: javascript, html, templates

I downloaded an html5 template and tried customizing it, but I'm in over my head.
The website I want is very simple. You can see the demo here:
[Demo Website](http://demo.html5xcss3.com/demo.php?cat=html5themes&host=templatesmonster&temp=hathayoga)

As you can see when the menu is clicked, there's slide-in content comes up on the right.
So there's two things I'm hoping I could get advice on:

1.) I would like to modify the width and height of this content and can't figure out how to do it.

Here is the javascript I believe is responsible for it:

```
$(window).load(function() { 
var act='';

$('#content > ul > li').css({position:'absolute', display:'none'});
$('#content > ul > li').find('.box1').css({height:'0'})

$('#menu > li > a span').css({opacity:'0'})

$('#menu > li > a').hover(function(){
    $(this).find(' > span').stop().animate({opacity:'1'},600);                         
}, function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).find(' > span').stop().animate({opacity:'0'},600);                         
    }
})

$('#menu > li').each(function(num){
    $(this).data({num:num})
})
if (location.hash.slice(0,3)=='#!/') {
    page=location.hash.slice(3);
    open_page('#'+page);
}
if ((location.hash=='#')||(location.hash=='')) {
    open_page('');
}
$('#menu a').click(function(){
    $('#menu a').removeClass('active').find(' > span').stop().animate({opacity:'0'},600);
    Cufon.replace('#menu a', { fontFamily: 'Questrial', hover:true });
    $(this).addClass('active').find(' > span').stop().animate({opacity:'1'},600);   
})
$('a').click(function(){
    if ($(this).attr('href').slice(0,3)=='#!/') {
        page=$(this).attr('href').slice(3); 
        open_page('#'+page);
        return false;
    }
    if ($(this).attr('data-type')=='close') {
        close_page()    
    }
})
function open_page(page){
    location.hash='#!/'+page.slice(1);
    if (act!='') {
        $(act).find('.box1').stop().animate({height:'0'},700,'easeOutCirc', function(){
            $(act).css({display:'none'});
            $(page).css({display:'block'}).find('.box1').stop().animate({height:'100%'},700, 'easeOutCirc', function(){
                act=page;           
            }); 
        })
    } else {
        $(page).css({display:'block'}).find('.box1').stop().animate({height:'100%'},700, 'easeOutCirc', function(){
            act=page;           
        });     
    }
}
function close_page(page){
    $('#menu a').removeClass('active').find(' > span').stop().animate({opacity:'0'},600);
    Cufon.replace('#menu a', { fontFamily: 'Questrial', hover:true });
    location.hash='#';
    $(act).find('.box1').stop().animate({height:'0'},700,'easeOutCirc', function(){
        $(act).css({display:'none'});
        act='';
    }); 
    return false;
}
```

})

2.) I would like to open another page (not hosted on the same server) within that slide-in content space, like a jquery pop-up but embedded inside that slide-in window. Currently, all the content there is written in the index.html

Should I do so with an iframe? I haven't tried yet because I need to figure out step 1 first.

Like this:

```
<li id="page_Teachers">
                    <div class="box1">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-type="close"><span></span></a>
                            <div class="wrapper">
                                <h2>Our Staff</h2>
                                <div class="wrapper pad_bot2">
                                    <figure class="left marg_right1"><img src="images/page2_img1.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                                    <p class="pad_bot2"><strong>Helen Williams</strong></p>
                                    <p class="pad_bot1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor inciddunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua nostrud exercitation.</p>
                                    <p class="pad_bot2"><a href="#!/page_More" class="link1">Read More</a></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="wrapper pad_bot2">
                                    <figure class="left marg_right1"><img src="images/page2_img2.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                                    <p class="pad_bot2"><strong>Jessy Hamper</strong></p>
                                    <p class="pad_bot1">Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolorreprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore.</p>
                                    <p class="pad_bot2"><a href="#!/page_More" class="link1">Read More</a></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="wrapper pad_bot2">
                                    <figure class="left marg_right1"><img src="images/page2_img3.jpg" alt=""></figure>
                                    <p class="pad_bot2"><strong>Chester Hamper</strong></p>
                                    <p class="pad_bot1">Cupidatat non proident sunt culpa officia deserunt mollit anim idst laborum. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet.</p>
                                    <p class="pad_bot2"><a href="#!/page_More" class="link1">Read More</a></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Comment: Do you want to modify the `height` and `width` dynamically or do want it do be a fixed size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS `id` selectors for those containers are:

`page_about, page_teachers, page_schedule, page_prices, page_more`.  As seen here:

```
<li id="page_About" style="position: absolute; display: block;height: 400px;width: 600px;">
<li id="page_Teachers" style="position: absolute; display: none;">
<li id="page_Schedule" style="position: absolute; display: none;">
...
```

So, you need to add some CSS `width` and `height` to them.  For example:

```
#page_about, #page_teachers, #page_schedules, #page_prices, #page_more {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: @user2049635 Yes, for (2) you could try adding an `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take your CSS into account as well. Maybe start by playing with your css values, for example:

```
.main { width: 980; }
#content { width: xxx }
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, found it in the css! :)